# How to receive message over TCP and convert and forward as HTTP using HAProxy

Tags: http, tcp, converters, haproxy

I am trying to take a message (text string, JSON) over a TCP connection on port 8082 and forward it as an HTTP request to an apache server on port 80 (on the same machine). I think my configuration is not right since it is not working =)

**Conf:**

```
frontend sample_httpd
bind *:8082
mode tcp
default_backend sample_httpd
option tcplog
http-request set-method GET

backend sample_httpd
balance roundrobin
mode http
server master 127.0.0.1:80 check
```

**Log:**

```
Sep 20 20:42:28 DR-tracktape haproxy[2147]: 185.205.225.36:42593 [20/Sep/2023:20:42:28.125] sample_httpd sample_httpd/master 1/0/500 0 – 1/1/0/0/0 0/0
```

Answer (score -1):

*[because of reputation less than 50, I am not able to post a comment above.]*

I just wanted to know, did you specify any timeouts in your default section?

The reason is, in the logs I see '**0 -**', which is actually a placeholder for timers, it should report elapsed time between request and response phase, while in your case it is zero.

try these timeouts in default section, in case if you have not done so, or share here the complete haproxy.cfg file

```
defaults
    timeout connect 5s
    timeout client  30s
    timeout server  30s
```

**And I think, there is no need for balance roundrobin, since you only have 1 server (master).**